# Random number, whose range is an array's elements

Tags: c, arrays, random

Being new to C, I'm trying to become familiar with the random number generator. I know how to get a random number between a certain interval (Like 1 and 100), but I'm curious as to if it's possible to get a random number that's range is inside an array's elements? Would I use rand() for this? I tried searching for some answers online to this challenge, but came up short in finding a solution. An example, if I had an array:

```
Array[10] = {50,26,29,10,78,12,45,83,39,55};
```

And I wanted to create a random number that's ending value is a number in the array, how would I do this in C?

Comment: Shuffle the index and pick the number from the array.

Comment: `man random` will push you on the track.

Comment: Why don't you get a random number between 0 and 9 and output the arr[randomnumber]?

Comment: hint: rand() % 10

Answer (score 2):

Simply generate a random number that's an index into the array, and read out the number at that location.

```
const int index = rand() % (sizeof Array / sizeof *Array);
const int value = Array[index];
```

Note that using modulo like this doesn't give you the best random numbers, but it should work at least.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick a random index and access it.

```
Array[rand() % 10];
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. I wasn't sure how to implement rand() in my program to do this, but it seems so simple now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a random index.

```
index = rand() % 10;

A[index]  // This gets a random value in your range
```